# how do I extract a full path out of a string in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

Say I have the following string in a bash script

```
"stuff qrg eqrhqe stuff wthwr /this/is/a/full/path/to/a/fils.txt sadf ergwqe"
```

How can I extract `/this/is/a/full/path/to/a/fils.txt` from this string in a `bash` script.

Knowing that:

1. the extension of the file can change
2. It might be a directory (so no `.ext`)
3. the should be only one "path" in this string to look for

Comment: Can your full path contain white spaced also?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: IMHO, it would be easier to start thinking what would be there in common in the strings you would like to extract.

Comment: @anubhava good point: no space

Comment: @Inian I remove before `/` with `sed` then `tr` on ` ` but I look for something authoritative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `grep -o`:

```
str="stuff qrg eqrhqe stuff wthwr /this/is/a/full/path/to/a/fils.txt sadf ergwqe"
grep -o '/[^[:blank:]]*' <<< "$str" | head -1
/this/is/a/full/path/to/a/fils.txt
```

`head -1` is to ensure we display only first path starting with a `/`

Comment: what is `<<<` and why not grep -o regexp "$str" ?

Comment: `<<<` is called here-string, it feeds input as a string to `grep` comman

Comment: what's the advantage over  grep -o regexp "$str" ?

Comment: `grep` will consider `$str` a file in that case.